# How do you use access the information from a string*?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am using a doubly linked list and I am trying to use the data that is   passed by reference to insert a node before said data. I've used `string* data = new string(s);` to allocate memory however, when I try to use data I get an error.

```
    #ifndef __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
    #define __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
    //
    //
    #include
    #include
    using namespace std;

    class DoublyLinkedList {
    public:
      DoublyLinkedList();
      ~DoublyLinkedList();
      void append (const string& s);
      void insertBefore (const string& s);
      void insertAfter (const string& s);
      void remove (const string& s);
      bool empty();
      void begin();
      void end();
      bool next();
      bool prev();
      bool find(const string& s);
      const std::string& getData() const;

    private:
      class Node
      {
      public:
      Node();
      Node(const string& data);
      ~Node();
      Node* next;
      Node* prev;
      string* data;
      };
      Node* head;
      Node* tail;
      Node* current;
      };

  void DoublyLinkedList::insertBefore(const string& s)
  {
  Node* ptr = head;
  string* data = new string(s);
  if (head == NULL)
   { 
        append(s);
        return;
  }
  if (head == current)
  {
        //this is where I get an error...
        this->data= new Node();
        current->prev = head;
        current = head;
        return;

  }
```

Comment: *why* do you have a pointer to string in the first place? That is wrong in nearly all cases

Comment: Also please include the error message (see also [mcve]). But `this->data= new Node();` can't be correct, because `data` is a `string*`,  not a `Node*`

Comment: `this->data= new Node();` - yeah as Unholy sheep said, this looks wrong. Why do you need to do `this->` to access a member - it should probably be: `tail = new Node()` or somthing...  If you have your error levels cranked up you should get a warning about that (if you don't already)...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use a pointer to a `string`, which forces you to manage memory. Use a simple `string` instead.

But this is not the problem here.  Here a local variable has the same name than a class member of a `Node` , and the member in node gets never initalized.  Furtherthermore the `DoublyLinkedList` has itself no such member, so `this->data` is unknown.   See my comments here:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::insertBefore(const string& s)
{
    ...
    string* data = new string(s);   // --> ok, but this is local variable
    if (head == NULL)
    { 
        append(s);     
        return;     // ouch !!!  memory leak !! data pointer is never freed
    }
    if (head == current)
    {
        //this is where I get an error...
        this->data= new Node();     // --> 'this' is a DoublyLinkedList, not a Node 
        ...
        return;
  }
```

Now this being said, is it possbile that you make a confusion between the `DoublyLinkedList` and the nodes it contains ?  See here a start of correction, but you need to do more to handle the linking between the nodes:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::insertBefore(const string& s)
{
  Node* ptr = head;
  if (head == NULL)
  { 
        append(s);     
        return;     
  }
  if (head == current)
  {
        string* data = new string(s);
        Node nd = new Node();
        nd->data = data;        // initialize node's pointer
        nd->prev = ...          // you need to link new node to the rest
        nd->next = ...  
        ...                    // and you need to update the previous and next node
        return;
  }
```

Now, as said in the first place, replace the pointer to string with a string. At least, you'll avoid leaking memory, shallow copies, and lots of other troubles.  Then you can focus better on the real problems of a linked list data structure.